# ASP.NET Core 6 Minimal web API Deploy To IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I tried to deploy my web API of .NET 6 in IIS SERVER in windows machine. I have done all the necessary configurations:

- Adding IIS_USERS Access to web.config
- creating pool with no managed code
- installing ASP.NET Core Module/Hosting Bundle
- Install .NET 6 SDK

After doing all these steps, I get this:

> No web page was found for the web address: http://localhost:5100/swagger/index.html.

When I compare it to ASP.NET core 3.1, I see that the minimal api doesn't generate a runtimes folder.

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean minimal api doesn't generate a runtimes folder? I'm not sure how you set starup file and appsetting.json and if they are right. So please try to create a new empty application from template and deploy it on IIS. Check if it returns same error.

Comment: In .NET 6 there are no startup.cs file they include it in programe.cs file

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue and now it is working OK

In publish settings, I have

Configuration: Release
Target Framework: net6.0
Deployment Mode: Self-contained (this was framework-dependant before)
Target Runtime: win-x64

Give it a try

Answer (score 0):

**Just set the IIS port for the site.**

That worked for me

From the left-side menu of the IIS manager, right-click on sites, then choose 'Add Website'. Configure the app and in Binding set the port to a valid one as shown in the image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDebg.png).

If you already have the site configured, you can right-click on the site and go to 'edit bindings'

[Add Web Site Dialog image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDebg.png)